# Polynomial regression and plotting in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, polynomials

Given a set of points `x` and a set of values `y`, I am trying to compute the polynomial that best fits `P(x) = y` in the least squared sense. The function should display the Vandermonde matrix, and the output polynomial `c` should be plotted as a function in form p (x) = c0*x^0 + c1*x^1 + c2*x^2 + ..... + cn-1^(n-1).

I would like to see clearely the points (xi,yi) on the same plot, where the function is plotted.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
function c = interpolation(x, y)
    n = length(x);
    V = ones(n);
    for j = n:-1:2
         V(:,j-1)  = x.*V(:,j);
    end
     c = V \ y;
     disp(V) 
    for i = 0:n-1
      fprintf('c%d= %.3f\n', i, c(i+1));
    end

    x = linspace(-1,2,-100);
    y = polyval(c,x);

    x0 = x;
    y0 = polyval(c,x0);

    plot(x,y,'b-')
    hold on; 
    plot(x0,y0,'ro') 
    hold off;
```

Comment: This isn't clear.  What is the "real curve" here?

Comment: the "real" curve I mean the curve that really represents this polynom: -2*x^0 + 9*x^1 + 9*x^2 - 7*x^3. The polynom is defined by the coeficients c, that are the output of the function, that are calculated in line 7. The plot we are seeing is just a plot of the 5points, connected by straight lines. the points (xi,yi) are the input at the beggining (-1,5) (0,-2) (1,9) and (2,-4). We passed them as 2 vectors at the beginning x and y.

Comment: Well you're only plotting the input.  So don't be surprised that you only see the input!

Comment: Karim, I edited your post for clarity, let me know if I missed something.

Comment: thank you Sh3ljohn. But the image and the code I posted could help.. you deleted them

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Ok. How can i plot the polynomial function -2*x^0 + 9*x^1 + 9*x^2 - 7*x^3, using a function, which becomes as input any vector like for ex v1 = [-2 9 9 -7] or v2 = [-4 -5 2 5 6 1 2] which will be the polynomial function -4*x^6 - 5*x^5 + 2*x^4 + 5*x^3 + 6*x^2 + 1*x^1 + 2*x^2

Comment: @KarimBelkhiria Nothing is lost if you want to put them back, but I don't think they're adding anything to your question.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I edited the question now. I hope it is a bit more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take a look at [`polyval`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html) and [`linspace`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) if you don't already know it. Also take a look at [`polyfit`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html), which does the interpolation for you with a given degree. Here is your corrected code:

```
function [p,V] = interpolation(x0,y0,N)

    % format the inputs as columns
    x0 = x0(:);
    y0 = y0(:);

    % Build up the vandermonde matrix
    n = numel(x0);
    disp('Vandermonde matrix:');
    V = fliplr(bsxfun( @power, x0, 0:(n-1) ))

    % compute the coefficients of the fitting polynomial
    p = V \ y0;

    % plot the polynomial using N values
    x = linspace( min(x0), max(x0), N );
    y = polyval(p,x);

    plot(x,y,'b-'); hold on;
    plot(x0',y0','ro'); hold off;

end
```

Note: the coefficients of the polynomial, returned as `p`, are reversed compared to your indexing, ie they are sorted by decreasing power.

Comment: it didnt work; I got a blank-plot. I will edit my question and add my code. You can execute it and see.

Comment: @KarimBelkhiria You really need to work on your question posing, the original post did not even mention polynomial regression.

Comment: and if I want to check if some value exists 2 times in the x0 vector? is there a command in matlab for that? Because the x0 vector should not contain any value 2 times. How is that possible?

Comment: Have a look at `unique`, and make sure you apply the same to `y` :)

Comment: should y also not contain a value more than 1 time?